# Updating droplink field value by name

Tags: sitecore-api

I'm trying to update a droplink field value using its name but I get the following error:

> Value not in the selection list

The code is

```
item.Fields["__Subitems Sorting"].Value = sort; // sort contains the name ("Reverse")
```

As far as I understand, they expect me to pass the ID instead of the name but how can i retrieve it from the name?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subitem sorting has the datasource pointing to the path `/sitecore/system/Settings/Subitems Sorting`.

Since you have the name of the sorting type, you can find the item from the container and then assign it to the `__Subitems Sorting` field.

```
public void SetSorting(Item item, string sortType)
{
    var sortItem = Factory.GetDatabase("master").GetItem(new ID("{B01EB085-82BC-4D79-B15F-90EAB9E98062}")).Children
        .FirstOrDefault(w => w.Name.Equals(sortType));

    if (sortItem != null)
    {
        item.Editing.BeginEdit();
        item.Fields["__Subitems Sorting"].Value = sortItem.ID.ToString();
        item.Editing.EndEdit();
    }
}
```

The ID `{B01EB085-82BC-4D79-B15F-90EAB9E98062}` is the Sitecore Id for the item `Subitems Sorting`. You can use the path if you want.

Comment: I took inspiration out of your code : var sortItem = Factory.GetDatabase("master").GetItem(item.Fields["__Subitems Sorting"].ID).Children
        .FirstOrDefault(w => w.Name.Equals(sort)); and it seems that children is empty . Do you know what could cause this problem ?

Comment: Do you already have the sort name you want to add to the sorting field?

Comment: Yes i want to use "Reverse" for example. That's what the sort variable contains.
I debugged it with a quick watch. It seems the problem comes from Children. It contains nothing

Comment: So, you will need to first get the item. All the options are found under the path `/sitecore/system/Settings/Subitems Sorting`. Try to use the above code as is because the sort variable that you have already has the same name as the one from the list of items under the Subitems Sorting

Comment: But yes, that's what i want! i want to select "Reverse" which already exists in the droplink field. In your message, you are suggesting to split the logic in 2 lines ? first i get the item and then another line for getting the "Reverse" Item ?

Comment: When you are using `GetItem(item.Fields["__Subitems Sorting"].ID).Children`, it will return 0 because `item.Fields["__Subitems Sorting"].ID` will be the selected value from the droplist. Let say you have `Created` in the Sorting field and you have the value (Reverse) in the sort variable, using the code I provided in the answer will allow you to set the field value to reverse. Maybe I am misunderstanding your question, if possible can you explain it in more details.

Comment: Ok i tried again exactly like you wrote and it works. I think i understand my mistake now but i need to find a solution to get rid off this ID in my code. I don't really like that. Thank you a lot for your help

Comment: For the ID, it will always be the same as this comes directly from Sitecore installation. What you can do is to put it into a constant or you can use the path. But using ID is more efficient

Comment: Alright, i will keep this in mind ! Thank you again